# Ubuntu 18.04 netplan configuration for aws ec2 instance

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, routes, ubuntu-18.04, netplan

In Ubuntu 16.06, I was adding another interface with following configuration

```
auto ens4
iface ens4 inet dhcp
sudo ip route add default via 10.10.8.1 dev ens4 table ens4_rt
sudo ip rule add from 10.10.8.0/25 lookup ens4_rt prio 1000
sudo ip route add 172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 table ens4_rt
sudo ip route flush cache
```

in file:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/ens4.cfg
```

What will be the equivalent configuration for ubuntu 18.04 here with netplan  ?
I'm trying with following config, please confirm if this is correct & how to add docker0 related route, I wasnt able to find more about it  ?

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd #this line is added#
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 0:2:6:e:1:a
            set-name: ens3
        ens4:  ## added configuration from here ##                             
            addresses:
             - 10.10.8.0/25
            dhcp4: no
            routes:
             - to: 0.0.0.0/0
               via: 10.10.8.1 # Default gateway
               table: ens4_rt
             - to: 10.10.8.5
               via: 0.0.0.0
               scope: link
               table: 1000    
            routing-policy:
              - from: 10.10.8.5
                table: 1000
```